# Jms Template not receiving messages in transaction

Tags: java, spring-transactions, spring-jms, jmstemplate

configuration class

```
 package jms;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory;  
import org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;  
import org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;  
import org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager;  
import org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy;  
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;  
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;  
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan("jms")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Configuration {

    @Bean 
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL( "tcp://localhost:61616");

        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean 
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JmsTransactionManager p = new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory());
        return p;
    }
}
```

Receiver Class.

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ReceiverClass {

   @Autowired
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

   @Transactional
    void func() {
       while (true) {
           Message message = jmsTemplate.receive("tempQueue.queue");
           System.out.println(message.toString());

           throw new RuntimeException();
       }
   }
}
```

Main Class

```
package jms;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Configuration.class);

        ReceiverClass r =  (ReceiverClass) applicationContext.getBean("receiverClass");

        r.func();
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>  
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.3</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>  

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What i want is to retrieve a message from queue using jmsTemplate and do some processing , if something goes wrong message retrieved is stored back in the queue. But i am not able to achieve it using configuration as mentioned and messages are getting deleted from queue when read even some exception is getting thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a test and it works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48774170Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48774170Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template, Foo foo) {
            return args -> {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
                try {
                    foo.test();
                }
                catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    // no op
                }
                System.out.println("OK:" + foo.test());
            };
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ConnectionFactory cf() {
            return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
        }

        @Bean
        public CachingConnectionFactory ccf(ConnectionFactory cf) {
            return new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
        }

        @Bean
        public JmsTemplate template(CachingConnectionFactory ccf) {
            return new JmsTemplate(ccf);
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(CachingConnectionFactory ccf) {
            return new JmsTransactionManager(ccf);
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
@Component
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate template;

    private int count;

    @Transactional
    public Message test() {
        this.template.setReceiveTimeout(5_000);
        Message received = template.receive("foo");
        System.out.println(received);
        if (this.count++ == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return received;
    }

}
```

and

```
ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1, destination = queue://foo, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1518553219346, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1518553219346, brokerOutTime = 1518553219359, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1030, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = bar}
ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1, destination = queue://foo, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1518553219346, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1518553219346, brokerOutTime = 1518553219359, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 1, size = 1030, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = bar}
OK:ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:gollum.local-59919-1518553219166-4:1:1:1, destination = queue://foo, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1518553219346, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1518553219346, brokerOutTime = 1518553219359, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 1, size = 1030, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = bar}
```

I suggest you run in a debugger; put a breakpoint in `func()` and verify there is a `TransactionInterceptor` on the call stack, a few stack frames down. If there's not, it means the `@EnableTransactionManagement` proxy mechanism did not work for some reason.

Also try turning on DEBUG logging to see if it provides any clues.

Note that it is recommended that you use a `CachingConnectionFactory` with the template to avoid opening a new connection for each operation.

Comment: I tried creating a datasource bean (for mysql ) and DataSourceTransactionManager and tried saving a record failing it by runtime exception . I could find a "TransactionInterceptor" in the stack trace and even the record saved getting rolled back. (transaction worked in this case). but i couldnt find "TransactionInterceptor" with jmstemplate and jmsTransactionManager.

Comment: The type of the transaction manager should make no difference - of course, using a DS TM won't help with your rollback - but the transaction scaffolding shouldn't change - so something else is amiss with your configuration. If you can post a complete, simple example that reproduces the issue someplace, I can take a look.

Comment: It's because `func()` is not `public`. Not sure why it worked with the DS TM.

Comment: That worked for me. Actually with data source and data source transaction manager i was using  different method which was  "public int Save () {...}". So yes "public " created the difference.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share steps how u figured it out. That will be very helpful.

Comment: I didn't notice it wasn't public so I was stepping through the initialization of the `TransactionAttributeSource` bean (defined in `ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration`). The attribute source default no-arg constructor calls `this(true)` which sets `this.publicMethodsOnly` to `true`. Voila.